# Keep location listener alive when phone sleeps

Tags: android, location

I have a location listener in an Android widget that is declared in class MLocation as,

private static MyLocationListener locationListener;

The widget starts a service which in turn creates the MLocation class. The MLocation class creates and registers the location listener on creation.

Everything works fine until the phone sleeps. When the phone sleeps (some time after it sleeps), Android kills the service and all classes created by it (MLocation too). On phone unlock, Android recreates the service which in turn, creates MLocation class etc. During phone sleep, the location no longer listens for changes (since it is killed). Is there a way to keep the location listener alive, even if the phone sleeps?

Comment: You would need to run `LocationListener` through a service. Check out [this tutorial](http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/simple-android-tracklogging-service.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. When the phone sleeps, no basically shuts down the CPU so that no applications are running. If you need to listen for location changes while the phone is sleeping, you'll need to prevent it from sleeping by obtaining a wakelock. Be warned that if you do that you will use up the battery pretty quickly and your users will uninstall your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of location while the phone sleeps, you need a [partial wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).  It's going to drain the battery quickly because you're essentially keeping the phone from sleeping, even when the user presses the power button (but the screen can still shut off).

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
```

You'll need to request permission for that via the manifest, and it'll be visible in Google Play (assuming that's where you're putting the app), so advanced users should know the implications of that.

Now I'll say what you'll read everywhere: Try to avoid using a partial wake lock because it will kill the battery and people will hate it.

OTOH, if your application absolutely requires it, this is how it's going to have to be.

Answer (score 0):

You should rely only on your `LocationListener`, you need to "re-think" all structure of your application. Probably registering a `LocationChangedReceiver` would be a good choise, along with other sources of actual Location.

Fore more details check out this great article by @Reto Meier: [A Deep Dive Into Location on Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html).